# How to run a Spring Boot application previously deployed on an application server in docker on AWS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, war, application-server

I have a Spring Boot application that needs to be deployed as a docker container on AWS. In our old production environment we packaged the application as a WAR file and deployed it to an application server. How can we package the application with the application server so that it can run as a docker container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Each Spring Boot web application includes an embedded web server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver). Just run the JAR in the docker container and your application will spin-up, there is no need for a separate application server.

Dockerfile can be as simple as:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Don't forget to use the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) to make the JAR executable.